# Error While sending Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have made custom TableCell and added the `Tableview` to the `UIViewController`. I wanted to send data from one view which is `UITableViewController` to the `UIViewController` in which I have implemented `tableView`. I am getting this error:

[image: error]

Comment: Please describe properly. I am confused what you are saying and attached other code too.

Comment: as shown in the above image i am getting the particular error while sending the data from the one view to another view.The data which i want to send is of NSArray datatype .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Storyboard` your Segue is connected between `UITableViewCell` and `ViewController` because of that you are getting sender as `UITableViewCell`. To solve this issue, simply remove that `Segue` and create one from your source `ViewController` to destination `ViewController` and set the same segue identifier after that everything will be works in a way you want.

Comment: I am sending the data from UITableViewController to UIViewController Named BookingHistoryViewController. BookingHistoryViewController is the class for UIView in which i have added the Table View to make CustomCells and to that CustomCell I have used BookingHistoryTableViewCell , you can see that in the method prepareForSegue

Comment: @Ronit What I'm saying is that In storyboard  your segue is connected beteween tableCell and ViewController instead of that you need to create between two ViewControllers.

Comment: @Ronit Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

You question isn't clear yet. Though i am giving you idea.
You must use **closure, delegate or notification pattern**.

supposing i am send message from `view1 to view2`. use the simple process to send data. But If you send from `view2` to view1 -> **In closure**,
`view2` :-> define the closure as

```
  var sendDataToBackController: ((String)-> ())?

@IBAction func DataSendFrom2ndVCTo1stVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
           if let handler = sendDataToBackController{
               handler("Message From ViewController3 to ViewController2")
              }


            _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
    }
```

and in `view1` :->

```
if let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as? ViewController2{
                vc.dataFrom1StVC = "message send from 1st VC"
                  vc.sendDataToBackController = {
                message in
                print(message)
               }                
               self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
            }
        }
```

**Please call the closure as soon above process i.e passing the data back to view1 from view2 and define the closure where you have created view2 instance as soon above. I am giving only idea. If you want to get detail code then please give detail of you question.**
Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help can you tell me how to Add the code because stackOverFlow does'nt all too many characters

Comment: You can add code as you liked in stackOverFlow. If you wanna marked code as  i had written above, first  you write the code in answer box as like you had written then  select code you want to marked and press (control + K) key. If my answer help you then please check my answer and upvote. If any confusion then ask me. Thank you